# Prove that if $n$ is an odd integer, then $n^2-1$ is divisible by $8$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have it proved for when k is odd, but when k is even, I get 8[q(2q+1)]. Is it correct to state that 8(Integer) proves that n^2-1 is divisible by 8?

Comment: $k(k+1)$ is always even.

Comment: I would say this is a [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1013284/11619). And [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/242543/11619) is an even better match.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases,  $k$ is odd so $k+1$ is even or $k$ is even so $k+1$ is odd. In either case we have one is divisible by $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Either $k$ or $k+1$ is divisible by 2. Then $k(k+1)$ is divisible by 2 and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Either $k$ or $k+1$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

$$n^2-1=(n+1)*(n-1)$$
If $n\equiv3\mod4$, then $n+1\equiv0\mod4$ and $n-1\equiv2\mod4$.

If $n\equiv1\mod4$, then $n+1\equiv2\mod4$ and $n-1\equiv0\mod4$.

Either way, we have $(4k)*(4k+2)=16k^2+8k\equiv0\mod8$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by induction:

This is true for
$n=1 (0)$
and
$n=3 (8)$.

For the induction step,

$\begin{array}\\
((2n+3)^2-1)-((2n+1)^2-1)
&=(4n^2+12n+9-1)-(4n^2+4n+1-1)\\
&=(12n+8)-(4n)\\
&=8n+8\\
\end{array}
$

which is obviously
divisible by $8$.